# Semantics of "write-once" variables for complex data structures

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, semantics, syntax, variable-binding

## Question

My use case for what is described below is not a language or compiler implementation, but finding a reasonable semantics for this feature in a an abstract calculus.

Ideally, you give me a name for this concept, with references to a language that implements it and how that is done, or a theoretical exposition of how it could be done.  Of course an original idea is highly appreciated, too.

A solution combining metaprogramming with an existing language feature is fine as well.

## Detailed examples

I don't really know whether the concept I have in mind already has a name.  I'm looking for a language feature by which you can declare variables referring to complex data types from their parts, as they were mutable, without them actually being mutable.

The essential part of what I imagine is not the controlled immutability, though, but the ability to "synthesize" an immutable structure implicitely from "assignment-like" forms.

Let's assume for now that such special variables are written as `<x>`.  As an example, take a Markov chain:

```
<x[1]> = 0
for n in 1:N {
    <x[n]> = <x[n-1]> + rand()
}
print(<x[2]>) # OK
print(<x>)    # OK (but I never wrote `<x> = ...`!
<x[2]> = 2    # ERROR (mutation)
<x[N+1]> = 3  # ERROR (usage after completion)
```

Note that:

- `x` is not needed to be "initialized", to an empty or uninitialized sequence or otherwise.
- When the whole `<x>` is used, it is "unified" from all the individual `<x[i]>`.
- I'd like the `<x[i]>` to behave just like single variables, as if the loop were completely unrolled to scalars `x_i`.
- As soon as `<x>` has been "unified", it can no more be updated.  At that point, `<x>` is assumed to be "complete".
- The errors should not occur just at runtime, but be statically detectable -- either as a type error, or after some other kind of  analysis.
- Arrays are just an example. In principle, the same concept should also work for `<x>` being a struct, and several fields of it  (`<x.foo>`) assigned after each other.

The code above is not trivially transformable to an initializer; it is expressible as an unfold, but I want this to work generally.  I can imagine that a system of this kind could more easily be designed when the components are statically known:

```
<x[1]> = 1
<x[2]> = <x[1]> + 1
sum(<x>)
```

can be simply rewritten as

```
<x> = (1, 1 + 1)
sum(<x>)
```

but that's not enough flexibility.

And I'm not doing Prolog, so only "unification" is not enough of an answer.  This is unification of mutation statements in imperative syntax.

## Ideas for realization

### Syntax

I can imagine something like a [VB `with` statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement), as follows:

```
with <x> {
  <x[1]> = 1
  <x[2]> = <x[1]> + 1
}
print(<x>)
```

but that's not quite as implicit as I want.  Also, at least it would have to allow arbitrary statements within its body, without imposing restriction on interdependencies.  And once that's possible, you could probably just infer the boundaries of the "`with` block" automatically as the largest range of expressions from the first mention of any `<x[i]>` to the first usage of `<x>`.

That could also be implemented by making `<x>` [transient](https://clojure.org/reference/transients) within the block, and persisting it at the end, but the thing I'm after is not to control mutability, but the implicit unification.  At least one would need a way to statically detect modification after persistification -- unlike how this works in Clojure.

### Special types

The direction I see most hope in is a special type system.  In that case, `x` might be needed to be "declared" at the beginning somehow.

I resarched substructural type system a bit, but think that none of them really does what I want: the restriction is not to use the components of `<x>` only a certain number of times, but to build up a thing by parts.  After that, the parts should be able to be used as much as one likes with immutable access.

However I could just be wrong, and there is a way to use some substructural system for this purpose.

Comment: Not an answer, but some relevant search terms to look into if you haven't already: [definite assignment analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_assignment_analysis), exhaustive pattern matching, [copatterns](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~abela/popl13.pdf).

Comment: At least 1.5 new ideas for me. Copatterns look like a hot candidate!